# New Admob has critical Error at Interstial AD?

Tags: android, admob

The error occur when I upgrade admob sdk to the newest (google play service) version.

At the legacy Admob, my code work ok. But when upgrade to the new one (google play service version) problem occured:

- After I call loadAd() Interstial Ad show ok, but when I close the ad --> my app is crashed.

I have spent 3 days working on it but no result. It's not my app problem because the same method for old admob, it worked ok. but now it's crashed?

The only thing I know is: when Interstial Ad is closed, my activity's oncreate method's recalled again and all variables which are not static is cleared then my app is crashed???

I still have no solution now and needing your help.

Thanks you!

Here is the code:

```
                if (GameActivity.interstitial == null) {
                    GameActivity.interstitial = new InterstitialAd((Activity) GameActivity.this);
                    GameActivity.interstitial.setAdUnitId(GameActivity.this.getString(R.string.admob_int_id));
                    GameActivity.interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        public void onAdLoaded() {
                            super.onAdLoaded();
                            GameActivity.showINTAd();
                        }
                    });
                }
                GameActivity.interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());



public static void showINTAd() {
    if (GameActivity.interstitial != null) {
        if (GameActivity.interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            GameActivity.interstitial.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: stack trace for the crash?

Answer (score 0):

When an interstitial (Activity) is closed your Activity's onCreate will be called again because it is restarting your Activity. Alternatively your Activity  may be restarting because your app is crashing.

I see several problems with your code:

1. You are using static code and attributes when you shouldn't.
2. You are calling interstitial#show() from onAdLoaded(). Don't do this. Call show() from a natural breakpoint in your app.